# MySQL, выборка данных порциями

Tags: mysql, sql

Идея в том, что бы реализовать загрузку данных порциями для пагинации. Но, в отличии от обычной пагинации, где рассчет происходит построчно, я хочу в качестве наименьшей единицы брать данные за 1 день (на картинке выделены эти группы).

То есть, нужно реализовать логику для стандартных в SQL, LIMIT && OFFSET, но для специфической выборки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Составил такой запрос, получить определенные записи для **n** количества дней могу, а вот пропустить дни - нет (в данном случае вернет записи для первых 5 дней)

```
SELECT *
FROM `events`
WHERE date <
    (SELECT DISTINCT (date)
     FROM events
     ORDER BY date, number LIMIT 1
     OFFSET 5)
ORDER BY date, number
```

Помогите дописать запрос, что бы можно было и пропускать **n** количество дней.

На данный момент сделал 2-я запросами...

```
# получение дат (параметры: последняя показанная дата и количество дат для выборки) 
SELECT DISTINCT (date) FROM events WHERE date > ? ORDER BY date, number LIMIT ?

# получаем данные по выбранным датам
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE date IN (?) ORDER BY date, number
```

Comment: А вопрос в чём?

Comment: @LEQADA помочь дописать запрос, что бы можно было  пропускать определенное количество дней

Comment: А если бы в Ваших данных была еще одна строка `1 | 2015-10-12` - Вы уверены, что данные за `2015-10-12` не укажутся на разных страницах? `ORDER BY date, number LIMIT 1 OFFSET 5` все-таки не проверяет содержимое записей. ТОлько тупо их отсчитывает....

Comment: @cyadvert Без проблем отрабатывает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну чтобы "пропустить" кол-во дней вам нужна точка отсчета. Она понадобится, потому что даты не линейные. Т.е. несколько дней могут отсутствовать. Т.е. в запрос ПРИДЕТСЯ передавать дату, с которой отсчитывать...

В вашем примере первые 5 записей Вы уже получили. Значит следующий запрос должен просить следующие 5, начиная, но не включая, последню известную.

Т.е. примерно так:

```
SELECT * FROM `events`
WHERE date>'2015-10-12' AND date <
    (SELECT DISTINCT (date)
     FROM events
     ORDER BY date, number LIMIT 1
     OFFSET 5)
ORDER BY date, number
```